# Property "preload" is not allowed?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide, sap-business-application-studio

I searched around but didn't find anything..

```json
{
  "_version": "1.1.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "id": "xxx",
    "...": "..."
  },
  "sap.ui": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "...": "..."
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "models": {
      "": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
        "settings": {
          "...": "..."
        },
        "dataSource": "xxx",
        "preload": true
      }
    },
    "...": "..."
  },      
  "...": "...",
  "sap.platform.hcp": {
    "uri": "webapp",
    "_version": "1.1.0"
  }
}
```

That's my manifest. I always get an error on `"preload": true` in Web IDE saying:

> *Property preload is not allowed.*

I read in some sites that it's because my version is maybe too old? And I don't really know how to change the version.

Is there a way to update the version? It's a cloud app and it stays on the cloud..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the value of the root `_version` to something **higher than `1.3.0`** according to the table *[AppDescriptor Release and SAPUI5 Version](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html#loiobe0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da__section_mkz_dgh_1cb).*
2. Remove all other `_version`s in namespaces such as `sap.app`, `sap.ui5`, ….
3. Reload the IDE.

[*Manifest model `preload`*](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/26ba6a5c1e5c417f8b21cce1411dba2c) is available only as of *UI5 version* 1.38.0<sup>[1](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/6daecfb20172d296ae3a47b2ed42f756404361e6)</sup>. And since 1.38 corresponds to the *app descriptor version* 1.4.0, Web IDE complains that `preload` is an unknown setting in 1.1.0.